# Automating the solitaire game

Tags: c#, python

I want to write a program by C# or python for automating the solitaire game. First, I need to detect images. For example, I must detect the position of hearts, clubs, diamonds and spades as well as numbers. What is the best way?

Answer (score 2):

There are different method to achieve this. Use 'Template Matching' method with openCV.

```
 def match_template(img,template_temp,threshold=0.9):
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template_temp,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    matches = np.where(res >= 0.9)
    return matches
```

create template from your card then manage your game.

see this [link](https://www.tautvidas.com/blog/2018/02/automating-basic-tasks-in-games-with-opencv-and-python/). he is doing something you want to do.